# How to set/edit password in django admin view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have two models (Customer & Driver) which subclass the built in User class from Django. I have added these two models to Django Admin. In my current implementation, I allow password field to be set and edited from the admin. The admin stores the password in plain text - which is both insecure and incompatible with django's auth system. So the customers and drivers can't login using the password we set.

[image]

I need this password field look like:

[image]

I need a way to store the password like django does. Where and how should I do that?

Comment: have you looked at django's [set_password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L58) method? the source code has plenty of answers to this broad question

Comment: @HeddevanderHeide Hi, yes, I know about this method. But how to use  it with django admin? 

I need to be able to create a new password when I create a new customer. Later when editing the customer, I need to be able to update it.

Comment: I have added screenshots to better explain what I want.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing but I'm pretty sure that you haven't used `set_password()` function.

The `User` class already has the capability of storing hashed passwords.

If you use it, the passwords will be stored like this:
[image: See the hashed password.]

You can even change the hashes used by Django by modifying the `settings.py` file. By default it uses `PBKDF2PasswordHasher` which is quite decent.

But if you want more security, you can use `BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher`

My `settings.py` file looks like this for all my current projects:

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.CryptPasswordHasher',
)
```

For more info, please read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/passwords/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about the set_password() method and I know the User class has the ability to store hashed password. 

But when I subclass the User model, password field displays as basic text input. I need to be able to process that. And also, I need to be able to allow the admin to update that later.

Comment: I have added screenshots to better explain the scenario.

Comment: @maSnun Could you check this and tell if this is what you need? http://blog.omederos.com/posts/2012/05/15/reseting-users-passwords-from-the-admin-site/

Comment: Not exactly that but it gave me important pointers. Thank you!

I marked your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @maSnun Glad I could be of some help. :)

Answer (score 0):

**admin.py**

```py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)  # User is Auth_User_Model
```

Comment: sorry i forget to add 'enter' in code......